# Can players buy Boots from a visiting StreetPass party?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening, streetpass

If I put Boots (which permanently add 2 movement spaces to a Unit) in the inventory of someone in my StreetPass party, and then StreetPass with another Fire Emblem player, can that other player then buy the Boots from my party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Here is a link that has a table of items that are not available for sale via StreetPass teams.

[Items that cannot be purchased via StreetPass](http://serenesforest.net/fe13/streetpass.html)

> **Sword**     Missiletainn, Sol, Amatsu, Falchion, Exalted Falchion, Parallel
>   Falchion, Mercurius, Tyrfing, Balmung, Mystletainn, Sol Katti, Ragnell
>
> **Lance**     Luna, Gradivus, Gáe Bolg, Gungnir
>
> **Axe**   Vengeance, Wolf Berg, Hauteclere, Helswath, Armads
>
> **Bow**   Astra, Parthia, Yewfelle, Nidhogg, Double Bow
>
> **Tome**  Valflame, Mjölnir, Excalibur, Forseti, Book of Naga, Goetia
>
> **Staff**     Goddess Staff
>
> **Item**  Naga's Tear, Boots, Bullion (S), Bullion (M), Bullion (L),
>   Supreme Emblem
>
> **DLC**   Dread Scroll, Wedding Bouquet, All Stats +2, Paragon, Iote's
>   Shield, Limit Break, Silver Card, Outrealm Item

Comment: It should be noted that you can recruit other players' avatars who have already used boots via Streetpass.